# setting the background attribute to transparent in editext dynamically

Tags: android

hi
how to set edittext background attribute to transparent dynamically.

```
setBackgroundColor()
setBackgroundDrawable()
setBackgroundResource()
```

these options only available .
how to set background totransparent with this methods.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Try to do startAnimation with specific animatin.

Comment: thanks for edited..please reply for this...

Comment: hi will you help me to achieve the wrapping effect for textview created dynamically.i have tried almost solution provided in stackoverflow site.but i found nothing is working out.will you suggest me a solution.

Comment: please provide a solution for this wrapping effect problem .It would be great..and timely help for me..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best and genuine way:

```
setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the setBackgroundColor() method and pass an eight-digit hex value in the form of AARRGGBB.

AA = alpha channel (this channel defines the transparency) 
RR = red channel
GG = green channel
BB = blue channel

So calling setBackground(0x880000FF) will set the background to a half transparent blue. 
The 0x at the beginning say that the following value is described in hex.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this

```
setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

You can also set in xml file in edittext .

```
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
view.startAnimation(new AlphaAnimation(1, 0));
```

Comment: is this right solution to display edittext in transparent way

Comment: you can set animationListener and perform actions onEnd ar onStart.

Answer (score 0):

Use

setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);